# Arduino multiple file object scope

Tags: scope, arduino

I would like to know what lacks in my code. The Arduino compiler, IDE version 1.8.0, generates this error:

> 'swSerial' was not declared in this scope

The code is these three files that are contained in a folder called "object_scope".

```cpp
//      object_scope.ino
//
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "mylib.h"
const byte rxPin = 2;
const byte txPin = 3;
SoftwareSerial swSerial (rxPin, txPin);

void setup() {
  swSerial.begin(9600);
  swSerial.println("Hello");
  printSum(4, 5);
}

void loop() {
}

//       mylib.cpp
//
#include "mylib.h"

void printSum(int a, int b) {
  int sum = a+b;
  swSerial.println (sum);
  // generates error "'swSerial' was not declared in this scope"
}

//       mylib.h
//
#ifndef mylib_h
#define mylib_h
void printSum(int a, int b);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `swSerial` well after `mylib.h`, so when `mylib.cpp` is compiled, the compiler doesn't know about `swSerial` yet. The easiest way would be for you to pass an instance of `swSerial` to `printSum`:

```
void setup() {
  swSerial.begin(9600);
  swSerial.println("Hello");
  printSum(swSerial, 4, 5);
}


[...]


void printSum(SoftwareSerial sw, int a, int b) {
  int sum = a+b;
  sw.println (sum);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

BulldogLowell @ [Arduino Forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=516817.0) provided another way, which I preferred.  His solution was to add two statements at the beginning of the `mylib.cpp` file.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
extern SoftwareSerial swSerial;
```

These 3 files are a simplification of a multiple file code with many calls to the SoftwareSerial library functions. In this context, reference passing to all these functions would be a little cumbersome.